# jest.mock() is not mocking Capacitor plugin in Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, jestjs, capacitor

I'm using Angular 17 with the experimental Jest builder for my unit tests and have tried the [instructions](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/mocking-plugins) from Capacitor for mocking plugins in Jest. I have created a `__mocks__` directory at the root of my project (adjacent to `node_modules`) and there I have created the directory `@capacitor` and there I have a file `device.ts` for mocking the Capacitor device plugin. The content of `device.ts` is as follows:

```js
export const Device = {
  getInfo: async () => ({}),
};
```

I would like to use this mock in my `device-info.service.spec.ts` file therefore I have the following setup:

```js
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { DeviceInfoService } from './device-info.service';
import { Device } from '@capacitor/device';

jest.mock('@capacitor/device');

describe('DeviceInfoService', () => {
  let service: DeviceInfoService;
  const deviceInfo = {
    model: 'iphone 15',
    osVersion: '15',
    operatingSystem: 'ios',
    manufacturer: 'apple',
  } as unknown;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [DeviceInfoService],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(DeviceInfoService);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should return the device info', async () => {
    Device.getInfo = jest.fn(async () => deviceInfo as any);
    expect(await service.getInfo()).toBe(deviceInfo);
  });
});
```

However my test fails with the following log:

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    - Expected  - 4
    + Received  + 7

      Object {
    -   "manufacturer": "apple",
    -   "model": "iphone 15",
    -   "operatingSystem": "ios",
    -   "osVersion": "15",
    +   "isVirtual": false,
    +   "manufacturer": "Apple Computer, Inc.",
    +   "model": "darwin",
    +   "operatingSystem": "unknown",
    +   "osVersion": "darwin",
    +   "platform": "web",
    +   "webViewVersion": undefined,
      }
```

Which shows me that the mock is not replacing the functionality that I'm testing. What am I missing in my setup?